# Mutex ( Lock File ) on a PHP file

Tags: php, mutex, flock

hi guys i searched a lot but i get stocked on this one

i have a Mutex class witch basically is using flock and it will lock a file just fine but my script is running over about 200~ above users so because of this my Server Hard Drive will always working a lot and this is very expensive for my work so i need a very simple solution to lock a file like flock but not touching the HDD .

i tested PECL extention ( i dont know this will fixed my problem either )
but its really hard to config and use it.

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you asking how you can lock a file on the hard drive without actually performing an operation on the hard drive?

Comment: @thatidiotguy yes exactly  - actually i want my script only run a file once at time and after the operation on that file finished the file unlocked and operate again again again

Comment: If you're on Linux, just lock `/dev/null`, it's a pseudo-file. No hard disk activity necessary. BTW I am pretty sure that even if you'd lock a true file, there wouldn't be too much activity on the hard disk - things like this should be cached by your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a ram drive under both Linux and Windows and store your lock files there. I have a similar system and since they are so small (empty files so only file meta data) even a few megabytes can store quite a lot of them. Another upside with this is that a system reboot will delete all lockfile's so no lingering ones are left on the drive.

**On Linux** you could add something like the following to `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M   0 0
```

**On Windows** you can download something like [ImDisk Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/) and create a ramdisk with that.

[image: ImDisk RamDisk Configuration Tool]